# Finding speed using the accelerometer

Tags: android, android-sensors

I found the acceleration along x, y, and z axes using the accelerometer. I successfully removed the effect due to gravity.My question is "How do I find speed using the above acceleration value ? ".

Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Amongst other things, PLEASE DON'T SHOUT (hence my edit fixing your title).

Comment: What makes you think you can get *speed* from an accelerometer? It measures *acceleration* (change in speed over time), not speed. *(not my dv)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. You need the initial speed, and then you can measure how the speed change. If you know the initial speed ( for example 0m/s), then you calculate the speed as v = at + inital speed.

But this would be a bad approach, as it seems you're not considering rotation, nor drift in measured values. I would suggest looking into using GPS coordinates instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the velocity (speed) for the current given acceleration (by Accelerometer sensor) and time, you can calculate it by using this formula:

**Formula for velocity as a function of initial velocity, acceleration and time.**

```
v = v0 + at
```

where,

```
v0 = initial velocity
v = velocity
a = acceleration
t = time
```

Also you can have a calculation idea on this link:
http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/physics/velocity_a_t.php